# Java appium tests - unable to start firebase emulator on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: java, appium, firebase-tools

I am trying to run test cases on Ubuntu 20.04 but Firebase server is not starting from the function within the test case

This function works fine on a mac. At first I thought it was wrong bash location, but Linux bash is also located at same location. I even printed the "args" variable value and its giving the correct output.
I tried starting server manually and then tests start running and passing.

From my troubleshooting it seems like the line

```
ProcessBuilder(args).start();
```

might be the main culprit. But since this isn't my code and I am not that familiar with java. I am having tough time fixing this. I have been googling from days but still no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

No error is being thrown, so that's also got me stumped. App launches in emulator and tests start running but all test fail since Firebase emulators are not actually running.

```
 public static void startFirebaseServer() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String dbCommand = "cd " + System.getProperty("user.dir") + " && " + StepDefinition.getProp("DB_COMMAND");
    System.out.println(dbCommand);
    System.out.println("Starting firebase server");
    String[] args = new String[] { "/bin/bash", "-c", dbCommand };
    System.out.println(String.join(" ",args));
    try{
       Process proc = new ProcessBuilder(args).start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    System.out.println("Firebase server started");
}
```

Comment: SUGGESTIONS:  1) print out `dbCommand` (or look at its value in the debugger) and verify that it's a valid filepath.  2) If it's OK, then execute `/bin/bash -c <<dbComand>>` from a terminal window, and verify it works,

Comment: its a valid path. I already tried that. I get an error - Directory doesn't exist. But that's wrong. 
if I just do copy path after CD and try to CD into it from terminal, it works. 

And the same thing happens on Mac as well if I try to copy and paste the output from mac into mac terminal. So this can't be an issue. 

Isn't that command starting a process? Isn't it a bit different than running the same line in terminal?
Even if I try
`/bin/bash cd /`
in mac or Ubuntu terminal, I get the same error. Directory doesn't exist, and that's false. "cd  /" command will work in all terminals.

Comment: if I just run 
`/bin/bash`

In Mac or Ubuntu. They both run without any issue. Sort of like launching the terminal from within the terminal.  So bash command works, CD command works. Everything works if you do them separately in terminal. Together they give error on Mac as well. But it still starts Firebase server on Mac. So running in terminal and starting process or whatever that java code is doing must be different.

Comment: Sigh.. I asked two specific questions: Q1) Is the DB_COMMAND property being read to build the dbCommand statement, and Q2) are you able to type in that exact dbCommand statement - prefixing it with "/bin/bash -c" - from a terminal prompt, and does it successfully start your Firebase server (from the terminal window)?   I *WASN'T* asking you to run "/bin/bash".  Remember - the only thing Java "ProcessBuilder()" does is execute the command text you give it. My suggestion was to help you verify if the command text you generated was valid for your particular Ubuntu environment.